# Cauchy theorem verification

Tags: complex-analysis

This question should be pretty straightforward so please don't get mad. I am to verify Cauchy theorem for the function $z^3 -iz^2-5z+2i$ if C is the curve $\vert z-3i\vert +\vert z+3i \vert = 20$ where z is a complex number. After some help found ot the parameterization to be $\sqrt{91} \sin t + 10i\cos t$. Can someone guide me forward?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|z−3i|+|z+3i|=20$ represents an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) (which is a closed curve) with foci at $3i$ and at $-3i$. The center is $0$, the semi-major axes is $20/2=10$ and the semi-minor axes is $\sqrt{10^2-3^2}=\sqrt{91}$. Hence your parametrization is correct. Then evaluate the integral
$$\int_C (z^3−iz^2−5z+2i)dz=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} (z(t)^3−iz(t)^2−5z(t)+2i)z'(t)dt $$
where $z(t)=\sqrt{91} \sin t + 10i\cos t$. This is not a pleasant activity! Finally you should obtain zero.

Comment: At last i found the value to be zero!!!

Comment: @Ayan Shah Congratulations for the hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Now compute the integral
$$\int_C f(z)\>dz:=\int_0^{2\pi}f\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\>\dot z(t)\>dt\ .$$